# resultado JavaScript en un input

Tags: javascript, input

tengo este código que genera aleatoriamente un valor alfanumérico pero necesito que ese valor generado esté dentro de un input tipo tex de un formulario para así guardarlo en la DB.
gracias por la ayuda.

```
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    return result;
}
var rString = randomString(8, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wSQBx/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pues es muy sencillo manipulando el dom con javascript es decir guarda el string que creas en una variable y luego con javascript le agregas al input el value de la variable que contiene el string entonces lo que contiene se vera en el input type text checa el codigo

```
document.getElementById('el_input_que_quieres').value = variable_que_contiene_el_string
```

Comment: Sería mejor mostrar el código completo de la solución.

Answer (score 0):

voy a ponerte un ejemplo con el código HTML de como lo haría yo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <input id="random_field" type="hidden" name="random_field">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Puedes ponerlo "oculto" de tipo "hidden" para que el usuario de primeras no lo edite o rellene.

```
function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
}

// Obtener el elemento input al que vamos a ponerle el valor
const inputRandom = document.getElementById("random_field");

// Ahora asignamos el valor al campo
inputRandom.value = randomString(32, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
```

Ahora en este punto puedes enviar el formulario o hacer más cosas.